# Showing/hiding div control according to RadioButtonList selected values using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to make div control visible/invisible according to RadioButtonList selected values using javascript.

The div is embodied in FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fv" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RootId"
DataSourceID="SomeDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit">

<EditItemTemplate>
    <div class="SubTitle">
        Fees
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="FormTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="FirstColumn">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="FormTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ftCtrl" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("ftList") %>'
                                DataValueField="Key" DataTextField="Value" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ft") %>'/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>


               <div runat="server" id="BreakdownDiv"  style="display:none" >
                   ...
```

And here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#<%= fv.FindControl("ftCtrl").ClientID %>').find('input:radio').click(function() {
    var Br = $('#<%= fv.FindControl("BreakdownDiv").ClientID %>');

    if ($(this).next().html() == 'New') {
        Br.show('slow');
    }
    else  {
        Br.hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
              $('#ctl00_ContentAreaMain_fv_Inv1_fv_BreakdownDiv').find('input:radio').click(function() {
    var Br = $('#ctl00_ContentAreaMain_fv_Inv1_fv_BreakdownDiv');

    if ($(this).next().html() == 'New') {
        Br.show('slow');
    }
    else  {
        Br.hide('slow');
    }
});
</script>                            

<table cellspacing="0" clientIDMode="static" border="0"   id="ctl00_ContentAreaMain_fv_Inv1_fv" style="border-  collapse:collapse;"> 
.
.
.
<div id="ctl00_ContentAreaMain_fv_Inv1_fv_BreakdownDiv" style="display:none">
```

Debugging the script I can see that the div control is being found but nothing happens - it's not being hide or shown when different radiobuttons are checked.
Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Finally found what was the issue.

The Div I was trying to hide/show contained table and from some reason the table content wasn't hiden/shown. I've did some restructuring, removed the div and made the show/hide on the table itself.

Thanks everybody for your comments. Hope this help someone in the future.

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: on asp:FormView make put clientIDMode = static and use FV as selector in your JS

Comment: Have u added required JQuery file in header section.

Comment: did you mean "var Br" is found? why your not using $([id$=BreakdownDiv]) instead of ClientID?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code for hiding and showing divs based on selction of values.
    OWNER is used as a constant here having the value "Owner".

```
   $(":radio[id*=rbl_saleby]").change(function () {
     var fetcheddata = $(".mainContainer").find("#saleby").find(":radio[id*=rbl_saleby]:checked").val();
                if (fetcheddata == OWNER)
       {       
                    $("#saleby").show();
                    $("#salebyowner").show();
                    $("#salebyALA").hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code make sure the div block is set to `div{display:none}`

Answer (score 0):

only a function with 2 radio and a div

http://jsfiddle.net/forX/WGLQx/

```
$("input[type=radio][name=radio1]").change(function () {
  if($(this).val()=='New')
    {
      $("div[id$=BreakdownDiv]").show('slow');
    }
    else
    {
      $("div[id$=BreakdownDiv]").hide('slow');  
    }   
});
```

I'm not sure you can get the text of input radio. I used value instead.